# SQL query efficiency of subquery in select vs inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a query with the following structure:

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1]
     FROM [dbo].Table2 AS [Extent4]
     WHERE (Table1.Id = [Extent4].Id2)) AS [C1]
FROM TPO_User
```

This query structure is usually used by LINQ as opposed to the following structure:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1], [Extent4].Id2
     FROM [dbo].Table2 AS [Extent4]
     GROUP BY [Extent4].Id2) AS [C1] ON C1.Id2 = Table1.Id
```

When I compare them, the second query has a shorter duration. Could someone explain the exact difference in execution of such a query?

And is it worth it to ever have a subquery in your select statement instead of an inner join?

Comment: Well, in the second query the count isn't in the end result. So the subquery can be optimized away. In theory at least. I don't know if the optimizer catches that.

Comment: Both queries _might_ optimize to the same thing, but, in general, correlated subqueries should be avoided, unless there is no other way to do it.  The second join option leaves the door open for more optimizations than the first, such as indices.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding:

- the **FROM** clause is the definition of the target.
- the **SELECT** clause is the projection (line-by-line) definition.

So the **FROM** clause load the data you need in memory and after that the projection is made on each line of your select statement.

So if you do a query (or call a function...) in the **SELECT** clause, you say that you want this sub-job to be done for each line of your projection. Seems quite heavy ;)

A little source about the running order of an SQL request : https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations

Hope this helps (and do not hesitate people to correct me if I am wrong)

(And if I remember well there is now an automatic feature to optimize queries in sql server. I think it will do the correction by itself, should it not?)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect both queries to have similar performance characteristics.  When doing performance comparisons, you have to be sure you do them correctly.  For instance, running two queries in a row is not a good comparison, because the table data has been loaded in to memory.

To really compare the queries, you need a quiescent server and cold caches.  That said, the execution plan can be a big help in understanding what is happening.

I would expect the correlated subquery to have good performance with the right indexes.  For your example, you want an index on `Table2(Id2)`.

Which has better performance in general?  Well, it is simple to devise scenarios where the correlated subquery is better.  For instance, if `TPO_User` has 1 row and `Table2` has 1,000,000 rows, then the correlated subquery will be better under almost any circumstances.